# Calling a class function

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, class, swift

I have my main GameScene.swift file and a facebookLogin.swift file.

I am creating a SKSpriteNode 'FBButton' from the class from the facebookLogin.Swift file and adding it to the to the GameScene via self.addChild(FBButton). The class had two functions touchBegan() and facebookSignIn().

When the user touches the sprite 'FBButton', touchBegan() acknowledges the touch of the button and it calls facebookSignIn(). This function then connects to the users Facebook. Everything is fine up to here.

I then want this function to call the ShowButtons() Function back in GameScene.swift.
I call GameScene().ShowButtons() which removes the FBLogin SpriteNode and adds 2 more SpriteNodes and downloads the users Facebook data into an NSDictionary.

The data obtains from the users Facebook, however the buttons do not generate an the FBButton isn't removed from the parent.

Please help me as to where I am going wrong.

```
class facebookLogin: SKNode {

var signedIn = false


override init() {

    fbButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "login_with_facebook")
    fbButton.xScale = 1.0
    fbButton.yScale = 1.0
    super.init()

    addChild(fbButton)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        let point = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if fbButton.containsPoint(point) {
            facebookSignin()
        }
}

func facebookSignin()  {

    var permissions = ["user_about_me",
        "user_birthday"];

    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if user == nil {
            NSLog("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
            self.signedIn = false
        } else if user.isNew {
            NSLog("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            self.signedIn = true
        } else {
            NSLog("User logged in through Facebook!")

            self.signedIn = true

            GameScene().ShowButtons()


        }
    })

}
}
```

Below is the show buttons script

```
class GameScene: SKScene {


let fbButton = facebookLogin()
var btnHostGame: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "HostGame")
var btnJoinGame: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "JoinGame")    



override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    userInteractionEnabled=true
    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    self.fbButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.fbButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5, y: self.size.height * 0.5)
    addChild(self.fbButton)

}



func showButtons() {

    self.btnHostGame.name = "btnHostGame"
    self.btnHostGame.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5, y: self.size.height * 0.6)
    addChild(self.btnHostGame)

    self.btnJoinGame.name = "btnJoinGame"
    self.btnJoinGame.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5, y: self.size.height * 0.40)
    addChild(self.btnJoinGame)

    fbButton.RemoveFromParent()

    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly except when it calls back to the GameScene. The buttons don't appear and the FBButton doesn't get removed.

Anyone know a solution?

Cheers
Ryann

Comment: in `GameScene().ShowButtons()` you are creating a new instance of `GameScene`, not accessing the existing instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `GameScene().ShowButtons()` you are actually creating a new instance of the `GameScene` class. This instance is not the one current added to the `SKView`. That is why it does not work.

Instead declare a *weak property* for `GameScene` in `facebookLogin` Node.

```
class faceBookLogin : SKNode
{
    weak var gameScene : GameScene? = nil
}
```

And add the gameScene from your `didMoveToView` function.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    userInteractionEnabled=true
    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    self.fbButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.fbButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5, y: self.size.height * 0.5)
    addChild(self.fbButton)
    self.fbButton.gameScene = self
}
```

This way you can call, your presented `GameScene` from `func facebookSignin()`

```
func facebookSignin()  {
   // Your code.
   self.gameScene.showButtons()
}
```